# Submit Button is not working. When i click on submit after put information in the field it doesn't do anything.

Tags: c#

```
// FrmWaterDepth.cs
// Graphical User Interface class
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace Ch12_WaterDepth
{
public partial class FrmWaterDepth : Form
{
private ShoalArea anArea;
public FrmWaterDepth( )
{
InitializeComponent( );
}
    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
double[ ] lowTides = new double[4];
double[ ] hiTides = new double[4];
anArea.Location = txtbxLocation.Text;
try
{
lowTides[0] = double.Parse(txtbLow1.Text);
lowTides[1] = double.Parse(txtbLow2.Text);
lowTides[2] = double.Parse(txtbLow3.Text);
lowTides[3] = double.Parse(txtbLow4.Text);
hiTides[0] = double.Parse(txtbxHi1.Text);
hiTides[1] = double.Parse(txtbxHi2.Text);
hiTides[2] = double.Parse(txtbxHi3.Text);
hiTides[3] = double.Parse(txtbxHi4.Text);
anArea.State = txtbxState.Text;
anArea.MileMarker = double.Parse(txtbxMile.Text);
anArea.LoTideDepth = lowTides;
anArea.HiTideDepth = hiTides;
MessageBox.Show(anArea.ToString( ),
"ICW Problem Area");
}
catch (TestOfStateException ex)
{
Trace.WriteLine("\nException: " + ex.Message);
lblError.Text += "\nException: " + ex.Message;
}
catch (System.FormatException ex)
{
Trace.WriteLine("Method's actual argument does " +
"not match formal parameter." +
"\nException: " + ex.Message);
lblError.Text += "\nException: " + ex.Message;
}
catch (System.ArithmeticException ex)
{
Debug.WriteLine("Errors in an arithmetic, " +
"casting, " +
"or conversion." +
"\nException: " + ex.Message);
lblError.Text += "\nException: " + ex.Message;
}
catch (System.ArrayTypeMismatchException ex)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("Trying to store an element of " +
    "wrong type in an array." +
    "\nException: " + ex.Message);
    lblError.Text += "\nException: " + ex.Message;
}
catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException ex)
{
    Trace.WriteLine("Trying to access element of an " +
    "array with index outside" +
    " bounds of the array." +
    "\nException: " + ex.Message);
    lblError.Text += "\nException: " + ex.Message;
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    lblError.Text += "\nException: " + ex.Message;
    Trace.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
}
}
    private void FrmWaterDepth_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        anArea = new ShoalArea();
    }

    private Button btnSubmit;
    private TextBox txtbxLocation;
    private TextBox txtbxState;
    private TextBox txtbxMile;
    private TextBox txtbLow1;
    private TextBox txtbLow2;
    private TextBox txtbLow3;
    private TextBox txtbLow4;
    private TextBox txtbxHi1;
    private TextBox txtbxHi2;
    private TextBox txtbxHi3;
    private TextBox txtbxHi4;
    private Label lblError;
    private Label label1;
    private Label label2;
    private Label label3;
    private Label label4;
    private Label label5;

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(FrmWaterDepth));
            this.btnSubmit = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.txtbxLocation = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.txtbxState = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.txtbxMile = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.txtbLow1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.txtbLow2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.txtbLow3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.txtbLow4 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.txtbxHi1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.txtbxHi2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.txtbxHi3 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.txtbxHi4 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.lblError = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // btnSubmit
            // 
            this.btnSubmit.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(288, 196);
            this.btnSubmit.Name = "btnSubmit";
            this.btnSubmit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnSubmit.TabIndex = 11;
            this.btnSubmit.Text = "Submit";
            this.btnSubmit.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnSubmit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnSubmit_Click_1);
            // 
            // txtbxLocation
            // 
            this.txtbxLocation.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(184, 69);
            this.txtbxLocation.Name = "txtbxLocation";
            this.txtbxLocation.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(179, 20);
            this.txtbxLocation.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // txtbxState
            // 
            this.txtbxState.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(184, 95);
            this.txtbxState.Name = "txtbxState";
            this.txtbxState.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 20);
            this.txtbxState.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // txtbxMile
            // 
            this.txtbxMile.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(184, 121);
            this.txtbxMile.Name = "txtbxMile";
            this.txtbxMile.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.txtbxMile.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // txtbLow1
            // 
            this.txtbLow1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(23, 215);
            this.txtbLow1.Name = "txtbLow1";
            this.txtbLow1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(37, 20);
            this.txtbLow1.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // txtbLow2
            // 
            this.txtbLow2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(23, 247);
            this.txtbLow2.Name = "txtbLow2";
            this.txtbLow2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(37, 20);
            this.txtbLow2.TabIndex = 5;
            // 
            // txtbLow3
            // 
            this.txtbLow3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(23, 280);
            this.txtbLow3.Name = "txtbLow3";
            this.txtbLow3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(37, 20);
            this.txtbLow3.TabIndex = 7;
            // 
            // txtbLow4
            // 
            this.txtbLow4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(23, 308);
            this.txtbLow4.Name = "txtbLow4";
            this.txtbLow4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(37, 20);
            this.txtbLow4.TabIndex = 9;
            // 
            // txtbxHi1
            // 
            this.txtbxHi1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(134, 215);
            this.txtbxHi1.Name = "txtbxHi1";
            this.txtbxHi1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(39, 20);
            this.txtbxHi1.TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // txtbxHi2
            // 
            this.txtbxHi2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(134, 247);
            this.txtbxHi2.Name = "txtbxHi2";
            this.txtbxHi2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(39, 20);
            this.txtbxHi2.TabIndex = 6;
            // 
            // txtbxHi3
            // 
            this.txtbxHi3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(134, 280);
            this.txtbxHi3.Name = "txtbxHi3";
            this.txtbxHi3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(39, 20);
            this.txtbxHi3.TabIndex = 8;
            // 
            // txtbxHi4
            // 
            this.txtbxHi4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(134, 308);
            this.txtbxHi4.Name = "txtbxHi4";
            this.txtbxHi4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(39, 20);
            this.txtbxHi4.TabIndex = 10;
            // 
            // lblError
            // 
            this.lblError.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblError.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(246, 294);
            this.lblError.Name = "lblError";
            this.lblError.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 13);
            this.lblError.TabIndex = 12;
            this.lblError.Text = "\" \"";
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(77, 71);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 13);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 13;
            this.label1.Text = "Location";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.AutoSize = true;
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(74, 126);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(62, 13);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 14;
            this.label2.Text = "Mile Marker";
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this.label3.AutoSize = true;
            this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(80, 100);
            this.label3.Name = "label3";
            this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(32, 13);
            this.label3.TabIndex = 15;
            this.label3.Text = "State";
            // 
            // label4
            // 
            this.label4.AutoSize = true;
            this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(17, 188);
            this.label4.Name = "label4";
            this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(51, 13);
            this.label4.TabIndex = 16;
            this.label4.Text = "Low Tide";
            // 
            // label5
            // 
            this.label5.AutoSize = true;
            this.label5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(127, 190);
            this.label5.Name = "label5";
            this.label5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(53, 13);
            this.label5.TabIndex = 17;
            this.label5.Text = "High Tide";
            // 
            // FrmWaterDepth
            // 
            this.AcceptButton = this.btnSubmit;
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("$this.BackgroundImage")));
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(392, 379);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label5);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.lblError);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtbxHi4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtbxHi3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtbxHi2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtbxHi1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtbLow4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtbLow3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtbLow2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtbLow1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtbxMile);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtbxState);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtbxLocation);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnSubmit);
            this.Name = "FrmWaterDepth";
            this.Text = "ICW SHoal Reporter";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

    }

    private void btnSubmit_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Submit Button is not working. When i click on submit after put information in the field it doesn't do anything.  I am not sure to put in after private void btnSubmit_Click_1. 
i am using VB 2010 and its a windows form project .

Comment: Trim down your code to the relevant area of issue.

Comment: Your implementation of `btnSubmit_Click_1` is empty and does not do anything.  Thats why "it doesn't do anything".  What is your question?

Comment: A little effort to present your code in a readable way would avoid a lot of downvotes

Comment: Please, next time post only code that is relevant to your question. And try harder to solve the problem on your own before you ask something.

Comment: As it stands this question is vague and incites pointless debate.  Voting to close.

Comment: I don't think it's vague.  I think it's clear that Mitul misunderstands how to hook up events in C#.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer That's laughable, considering he *couldn't* properly hook up the event to the method that actually has code.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer i am getting error when i click on submit "Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: What's laughable?  I'm just saying that he doesn't understand how to do this.  It's a simple answer as to why nothing is happening for him.

Comment: Ok, given Mitul's last comment, I'm in agreement that this should just be closed.

Answer (score 2):

You've linked two methods to your button.

```
private void btnSubmit_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

and

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Put your code in `btnSubmit_Click_1`.

**Alternatively**

You can adjust the method attached to the click event, by selecting the properties of the button in the design view, and clicking the yellow lightning bolt, and finding the `click` event, and changing the method name.

Comment: I am getting error when i click on submit "Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.btnSubmit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnSubmit_Click_1);
```

Your code in that method:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

You're expecting it to do what exactly?

I think you want:

```
this.btnSubmit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnSubmit_Click);
```

You have a terrifying number of other issues with your code, one being the "Gotta catch em all" exception handling in the *real* `btnSubmit_click`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to click handler methods: `btnSubmit_Click` and `btnSubmit_Click_1`.

Only `btnSubmit_Click_1` is registered to handle the click, and its body is empty. You can remove that method and change the registration to:

```
this.btnSubmit.Click += btnSubmit_Click;
```

Comment: I am getting error when i click on submit "Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.